# Gulp не видит новых файлов и изменений

Tags: node.js, gulp

Есть две задачи: "`templates`" и "`app`". "`templates`" проходит по всем файлам в папке "`templ`" и объединяет их в один файл "`templates.js`", после чего записывает этот файл в папку "`js`". "app" проходит по всем файлам в папке "`js`" и объединяет их в один файл "app.js".

Проблема в том, что задача "app" не видит новый файл "`templates.js`". Только при повторном запуске, когда файл уже существует, он его обрабатывает, но при этом обрабатывает версию, которая была на момент запуска. Если файл изменится в процессе, то он не заметит этих изменений. Такое ощущение, будто при запуске он кэширует всё дерево файлов и уже работает с ним.

Как решить эту проблему? Если вызывать эти задачи по очереди из консоли, то всё работает как надо. Задачи вызываю таким образом:

```
gulp.task('default', gulpsync.sync(['templates','app']));
```

Comment: Единственное что я нашел в момент возникновения подобной проблемы, это совет установить gulp-watch отдельным модулем.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Вот этот плагин помог решить проблему https://www.npmjs.com/package/run-sequence

Answer (score 0):

Можно использовать параметр deps в методе gulp.task https://github.com/gulpjs/gulp/blob/master/docs/API.md#deps

В вашем случае можно написать

```
gulp.task('app', ['templates'], function() {
  //do something
});
gulp.task('default', ['app']));
```

Answer (score 0):

https://www.npmjs.com/package/gulp-watch

Устанавливаем и используем вместо встроенного в gulp.
Гарантированно срабатывает при создании новых файлов.